# shouldComponentUpdate not working in child component React js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-component

when i'm updating my state using setState from parent component my child component get rendering(because props getting change) 
**Parent component**

```
    addonsHandler =(addons) =>{

            this.setState({addons:addons}, () => {
                // console.log(this.state.addons);
            });

        };
render() {

        return (
            <div>
                <Row>
                    <Col span={15} offset={2}>
                        <AntForm pickupHandler= {this.pickupHandler} dropHandler={this.dropHandler} addonsHandler={this.addonsHandler} ambulanceTypeHandler={this.ambulanceTypeHandler}/>
                        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.drop} >Drop</Button>
                        <Button type="primary" onClick={this.calculateRoute}>Direction</Button>
                        {/*<div id="map" style={{height: "600px"}}></div>*/}
                        <Map onRef={ref => (this.MapRef = ref)} />
                    </Col>
                    <Col span={6} offset={1}>

                        <BookingDetails  addons={this.state.addons} price={this.addonObj} ambulaceType={this.state.AmbulanceType} VehiclePrice={this.ambulacneTypeObj}  />

                    </Col>
                </Row>
                <Row>
                    <Col span={15} offset={2}>

                    </Col>
                </Row>

            </div>

        );
    }
```

**so i want to stop rendering only *Map* component when *addons* state get change in parent component**

so i used `shouldComponentUpdate` in **Map** component but it's not stoping rendering to component

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: can you show your Map component

Comment: i added that in https://jsfiddle.net/r0e8xa17/1/

Answer (score 0):

shouldComponentUpdate() affect on parent component. If it returns true, parent component will be rerender.
So, I think you should move shouldComponentUpdate() into BookingDetails component instead.

Comment: but i need that state in other component,so other component should render